# How to read this graph R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Sorry if this may come across as really stupid but I done some clustering using K MEANS in R and plotted this graph.

Could someone please explain me how to read this plot? or the name for these types of plots so i can google further.

Thank you[image]
 PS: for clustering experts can you identify any meaningful clusters from this plot?

Answer (score 0):

You effectively ignored all attributes except *quantity*.

The result is meaningless.

K-means only works well, when every axis has a comparable distribution.

Restart from the beginning, with **careful preprocessing**, scaling, and understanding your data.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am really confused with pre-processing my data. I am using a category dataset. Could you please point me towards the right links which show how to pre-process category data ? This would really help to find something meaningful. Or if you wish I can post a sample of my data on here for you to analyse and maybe you can suggest something? @Anony-Mousse

Comment: K-means does not work for categorial data. Use an algorithm designed for categorial data.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am trying to preprocess one step more from raw data so I can have some data which I can use to KMEANS, I am not sure if your an R expert but would you know how I can calculate the sum of unique values per ID?